# Background slider is distorted on mobile. (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

I am a full page slider for the background of my site, it works great on desktops. However, when I switch to a mobile device the picture is heavily distorted and has a black gap at the left of the page which doesn't look good at all.

Check out the attached photo for a visual or pull it up on your phone, the
 URL is http://plunderfest.muvltd.com

Any way to solve this with some CSS?

[image: Arrows are pointing to blank area on display]

(Edit) CSS as requested:

```css
#supersized {
display: block;
position: fixed !important;
background-size: cover !important;
left: 0;
top: 0;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: -999;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Body background image css:

```css
body {
background-image: url(http://plunderfest.muvltd.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/starry4.jpg) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-attachment: fixed !important;
background-size: 100% !important;
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
}
```

Only CSS with a max width of 767px:

```css
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .hidden-desktop {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .visible-desktop {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .visible-phone {
    display: inherit !important;
  }
  .hidden-phone {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product.one_fourth,
  .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.one_fourth,
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product.one_third,
  .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.one_third,
  .woocommerce ul.products li.product.one_half,
  .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.one_half,
  .woocommerce .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_fourth,
  .woocommerce-page .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_fourth,
  .woocommerce .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_third,
  .woocommerce-page .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_third,
  .woocommerce .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_half,
  .woocommerce-page .cart-collaterals .cross-sells ul.products li.one_half,
  .one_sixth,
  .one_fifth,
  .one_fourth,
  .one_third,
  .one_half,
  .two_third,
  .three_fourth {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .fimage-align-right,
  .fimage-align-left {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: What slider are you using and can you post the css?

Comment: I am using a slider for a theme called ultimatum, I also have revolution slider on hand but it is a pain in it of itself to set up as full page. I will add the css into my original post.

Comment: There is no need to use a slider as your background if you are just using one page.  It's a waste of time to go through the slider code to edit why it's not responding correctly on resize.  Just do what I posted in the anwer and it should work fine.

Comment: As mentioned below, I know how to set the background of the page. I don't know how to fix it to a set position though

Comment: Ok, so now the background only covers maybe half the screen on mobile and isn't fixed (working fine on desktop).                                                           I updated it to show you the current css for the body background image.

Comment: Ok, I posted the only CSS that has a max width of 767px (where the problems are happening), not sure if there is an existing issue in there or I need to add something to it so I just posted the string of code

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a slider for the background of your site if it just has one image?
I would recommend not using the page slider as the background and instead just use an image by styling it that way in css.  Something is happening in the css when it resizes.  If your set on using the slider as the background you'll need to go through the css of it when it is resizing.

If you want to use an image, use css so it doesn't scroll by using background-attachment.

```css
body {
    background-image: url('your/image/location/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

There are several ways to do this and I was giving you the quick note to use background-attachment, not the whole css for the changes.

Update

I see what it is.  It's not the responsiveness because the image shrinks up as it resizes.  Try resizing your browser's width but keeping the same height.  It's because the image cannot stretch and resize at the same time. It will keep the correct aspect ratio so it does not distort.  A very quick and easy fix for this would be to put a black gradient at the very bottom of that image in a photo editor.  This would give it the appearance that it was fading into the site background and would be much cleaner than having a hard line at the bottom.  It might also make things more legible not having the space scene in the background at that small of a size.  Other than that I am not sure how to make it adjust and if it did, it would have to stretch the mess out of that image to reach the bottom.

I found some posts [here](http://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/full-page-backgrounds-on-ios-background-size-cover/) where people talk about different solutions but there is not much info out there on this.  Try looking around or see if someone else has an idea.

Other than that I'm not sure how